# Java. How to specify server path when upload files?

Tags: java, outputstream

I need to programmatically save files (and create directories) to another server. How I can achieve this? In the other server there is a shared directory(write access), and want to write files here. I use

```
FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(fullFileName, false);
```

Where `fullFileName`
is

`////SRV0105-FSACL01/SharedDirectory/directoriesCreatedByMe/filename.xls`

I think server path is written not correct, may here some extra slashes?

**EDIT**: Operation fails on `dir.mkdirs()` command (this command return `false`);

Comment: Did you try with backslashes `"\"`?

Answer (score 1):

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(new File("////MY-COMP/Documentations/Java/Maven.pdf "), new File("D:/p.pdf"));
```

working well

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(new File("//MY-COMP/Documentations/Java/Maven.pdf "), new File("D:/t.pdf"));
```

also working well

Use class `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
     <version>1.4</version>
     <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

if both your 2 servers (one server is running java, the other is used to store file) are windows, you can setup \ServerComputerName\ShareName as Driver as F: and write F://filename.xls
If both are linux, start NFS service on the target server and mount on the exported folder in the server which java is running on.
if mixed environment, consider sftp solution, you can refer to [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)